# The overflowing RenderFlex has an orientation of Axis.horizontal. The edge of the RenderFlex that is overflowing has been marked in the rendering

Tags: flutter, user-interface

I need this yellow error go away.

[image]

i have tried a lot to overcome this error, but in vain.

**The Code Is:**

```
class SelectedImagesWidget extends GetView<AddProductController> {
  const SelectedImagesWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => (controller.images.isEmpty)
        ? const SizedBox.shrink()
        : SingleChildScrollView(
            scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
          child: SizedBox(
            height: 80,
              child: ListView.builder(
                    itemCount: controller.images.length,
                    scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                    physics:const NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                    shrinkWrap: true,
                    itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                      print("Assets= ${controller.images[index].name}");
                      Asset asset = controller.images[index];
                      return Stack();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Row` instead.

Like so:

```
 SizedBox(
      height: 80,
      child: SingleChildScrollView(
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        child: Row(
          children: List.generate(
            controller.images.length,
            (index) {
              print("Assets= ${controller.images[index].name}");
              Asset asset = controller.images[index];
              return Stack();
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

Comment: no, it does not work

Comment: What error do you get? @sunshine